# How does one use mod_rewrite to "move" the appearance of a site directory to the root without actually moving the files? Spot the error in my code!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I have at site where I want pages such as;

```
www.example.com/shop/index.php
```

(or any other page under /shop/ for that matter.) to now appear as

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

but without actually moving the files, which are still located under /shop/ but are now accessed via urls at /

Seems simple enough, and I can do that on its own using a RewriteRule, pretty standard. The second requirement is to keep the links to the old content working, so I want a similar thing but in the other direction, but using a **301 external redirect** (not rewrite), i.e.

```
www.example.com/shop/index.php
```

should 301 redirect to;

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

Again, simple enough on its own. But put the two together and you it gives you a lovely "This web page has a redirect loop" error when accessing a page. However, I don't understand why because one rule is a rewrite and one is a 301 redirect and they both have the L flag so I thought no more rules were processed. So, I am at the limit of my understanding of this mod_rewrite stuff.

To test, and avoid mucking up my site for people visiting, I am using the directories /blob/ and /b/ with /b/ being the *new* directory. The code I currently have that gives the redirect loop is;

```
RewriteRule ^blob/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example.com\/b\/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ /blob/$1 [NC,L]
```

I guess its because the first rule is being executed again once the second has, why is this if the 'L' flag is used? And what condition should I check or change to make so that the redirect rule only gets activated if the **original request** is for /blob/ *not* the rewritten URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without any need of an extra query parameter** you can use following rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shop/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L]
```

- First rule will send `301` to any request from `/shop/foo` to `/foo` in the browser, which is an **external redirect**
- Second rule will **internally redirect** any `/foo` to `/shop/goo` without changing URL in the browser thus making sure your actual files are served from `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/shop/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (I used your actual url examples):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/shop\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1?rewrite [NC,L,QSA]
```

The issue you are running into is that when `mod_rewrite` does the `rewrite` it is actually performing an `Internal Redirect`, which causes the rules to applied again.  So, this means you have to protect against that, in this case, I've added a parameter `rewrite` to the URL that the redirect checks for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in a bit. Are there any other conditions I could check to get the same result without adding a parameter? I can see this causing problems with needing to pass 'real' parameters through. Can I test for external vs. internal redirect?

Comment: I've added the `[QSA]` flag which will append the querystring from the original request to the rewrite.  So, `/index.php?product=1` -> `/shop/index.php?rewrite&product=1`.  This is really, the easiest solution, in avoiding a the redirect loop.

Comment: The http://localhost part doesn't work (it redirects the browser to localhost), but replacing it for the explicit full domain it works perfectly, it seems.